# nginx/php-fpm: changing status codes won't work as expected

Tags: nginx, status, php

I'm trying to build a simple pastebin application which receives the content directly via POST, so I can just upload a file via terminal using cURL (with the '-F' parameter). As Lighttpd (1.4) is generating "417 - Expectation Failed" errors and not allowing me to use cURL, I'm trying to set it up on nginx with PHP-FPM. To avoid using rewrite rules, I just redirect every 404 error to 'index.php' to deal with them. But I could not set the status codes correctly and I can't see why. Here some PHP/pseudocode with what I'm trying to do:

```
header('Status: 200 OK'); // Change it to 200, as the request could came via a 404 error.
if (there_is_not_a_parameter_in_the_url()) {
    if (file_is_in_POST()) save_file();
    else {
        header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently');
        redirect_user_to_other_page(); // It's not possible to post a file from web, only directly by sending a POST request
    }
}
else {
    if (entry_does_not_exists()) {
        header('Status: 404 Not Found');
        show_404_page();
    }
    else show_entry();
}
```

When the `show_entry()` function is called, the status code should be `200`, as it was changed in the begginning. But I'm still getting a `404` status code. The only time its is being changed correctly is when I try to set it to `301`, before the `redirect_user_to_other_page()` call.

Someone is seeing what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check if the error was from php not nginx